# Enemies don't collide with each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have 3 enemies created from the same prefab that aren't colliding with each other.

The prefab game objects have capsule colliders and a rigid body. Both gravity and kinematics are enabled and all of the colliders are Triggered. Their basic function is to chase a player character. As they do this, at the moment they all converge on the same point and end up overlapping each other. How would I get it so they collide with each other?

My hierarchy is as follows:

[image: The Hierarchy]

The skeleton setup is as below:

[image: Skeleton Inspector]

The attack sensor is set up like this:

[image: Attack sensor Inspector]

And these are my collision matrix settings

[image: Physics Matrix]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is barely any information to work with here. **Please** read through the page provided above and edit the post so we can help you better

Comment: What @Tofik would like to tell by pasting a link is that it would be very helpful for us to actually see a *minimal, complete and verifyable example*.

Comment: @NoelWidmer Yeah, sorry, should have explained.

Comment: To all those saying we lack info: His problem is not about coding, but a unity question. There is likely not a single line of code related to this problem. There is no way OP can post a minimal example other than posting a unity project. If you don't understand that when reading the question, you don't know Unity well enough to judge

Comment: Just in case i have posted my code  and a screen shot of my objects and there inspector.

Comment: If you just want to prevent the skeletons from overlapping, you could assign a PhysicsMaterial to it and give it some bounciness so that the they will not overlap

Comment: Your collider is not setup as triggered and setting gravity has no effect when kinematic. With kinematic you control the movement by script and not the physics engine.

Comment: Wheres the code?

Comment: If this is not about a programming problem, perhaps it's better posted on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com

Comment: Yes to [gamedev.se], definitely no to Superuser.

Comment: Related meta post: [Unity3d questions are often closed because too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375670/55075).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have `Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider` that is colliding with another `Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider` as shown here [unity collision messages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) it should work.

what about your colliding layers? is default colliding with default?(check in physics tab)

also, i did something like this time ago, can i sugest you to use one capsule collider for skeleton's body(not trigger) and a child object as attack sensor (sphere trigger collider is more fittable). this will help you separate body's physics and attack logic.

*answers in comments:*

*capsule collider: on your skeleton's transform with layer "default", not trigger

sphere collider: on an empty transform that is child with layer "attackSensors" or whatever, this one is trigger.

on collision matrix disable collisions between "attackSensor" layers, this will save you performance avoiding collisions between your attack sensors.

this way you can have:

1. a skeleton with a body collider that also use gravity(gravity won't apply on kinematic rigidbody) and respond to collisions.
2. a trigger that will fire the event when colliding with another skeleton's rigidbody.*

Comment: No it shouldnt, those are trigger, they never collide.

Comment: see yourself the table :)

Comment: yes indeed, trigger vs trigger are under "Trigger messages are sent upon collision" in this table, this means no visible collision, but just a trigger message

Comment: yep, this is why his OnTriggerEnter should work but he has issues with enemies overlaping, a good solution would be, as i suggested, using 2 colliders and separate logics, even better if he uses 2 layers

Comment: Ho, so we agree that he needs a collider that is not a trigger to actually see collision (no overlap). It wasnt clear sorry. Adding a second collider would do it sure.

Comment: Okay so as it stands right now my Skeleton collided with a simple cube game object given a box collider and a rigidbody  (is Trigger unchecked) Yet two skeletons (enemies) still overlap. I changed the OnTriggerEnter to a on Collision Enter and this codes function is working  allowing me to turn off the is Trigger for the capsule collider. any ideas :)

Comment: Not Sure i Understand what you mean by  using 2 layers ?

Comment: i edited answer explaining this layers since comment don't have nought characters

Comment: @victordabija I have edited the post to include screenshots of my skeletons Hierarchy, Inspector, Attack Sensor Inspector and what the colliders look like in game. cause still having a problem getting them to collide.

Comment: IT WORKS THANK YOU SO MUCH WAS A SIMPLE not ticking kinematic

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you setup the objects:

- **Kinematic** means that the object will set its values itself. Two kinematic objects won't collide (they don't let the object tell them what to do)
- **Trigger** means that the object doesn't collide. It just triggers a function that you can use in code. Unselect this to see collisions

In a more general way, you should be sure you understand which type of object can collide with each other. Have a look at the [Collider documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html). In the bottom of the page, there is a nice table explaining this.

Comment: Hi Basile. If i turn of the kinematic the objects fall through the floor and i have a  on Trigger Enter in my code to deal with the enemies colliding with the players bullets.

Comment: A collider that is a trigger will NEVER collide. If you want to see collisions but still have a method in your code, use onCollisionEnter instead

Answer (score 0):

Using the Unity animator typically makes the objects animated think outside of the games world space so really they're separate entities from the game. However, you can use raycasting to detect each others colliders and through this method make them appear to collide with one another.